# Execute a block of code once in a month only- Powershell script

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

i have a .ps script file job which runs daily(except weekends and holidays). i have block of code which should execute once in a month only. as it is a daily job so it should execute first working day of the month only. Rest of the code executes daily but this my own section should execute once in a month.
Is there any way i can keep the if condition in powershell script, how it knows after month changes????

Need inputs.

Comment: Create another a scheduled task that runs the once in a month part?

Comment: we cannot create monthly job now. it's not accepted timebeing.....so is there any other option?

Comment: Write to a file, and then you could check that file before running the once per month part.

Comment: Use the Windows Event Log for bookkeeping. When it's the 1st, poll day's logs and see if you already have executed the once a month part.

Answer (score 0):

```
$day = (get-date).day
$triggerday = 1 #if you want the script to execute on the 1st day of the month. "1" appears only once a month
if($triggerday -eq $day )
{
#Do something here
}
```